# use Jquery .load with login

Tags: javascript, jquery, authentication

I have a set of pages that I would like to ask the user to login. These pages are on a corporate site and the user must login through the corporate login.

Currently they come to my page, they can click login and they redirected to corporate. They login. Corporate Redirects them back. That two pages loads that arn't nessesary in my eyes. However I don't want to own my own login. What I would like to use is something like this:

```
<div class="ui-corner-all" id="RefRes">
        <div id="testloadlogin"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function loadlogin() {
            $('#testloadlogin').load('../security/login.aspx');
        })
    </script>
```

This works, I get the login box on my page, however when I click the login button it just does a postback. Nothing happen, the user is not logged in.

I am assuming this is because there is some server side code that is not getting executed.

Is there something I can do to make this work?

**Is there a way I can just get the username and password from the user and just send it to the other page to be proccessed? (securly of course)**

Comment: what is the form action set to in the login form that appears on your page?  is it relative or absolute?

Comment: neither is specified, so whatever it is by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this won't work, consider using an [`iframe`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html#h-16.5). The form-action in the loaded login-site form is probably a relative path or the login-backend checks where the request comes from.

Comment: very cool. I just tried it and it work sorta. I got an error about a secure connection, but I also get that error if I go to the actual login page because im running the site off of my server. So i think that might work. HOWEVER, do you know of a way to only show part of the page? I only want to show the login div???

Comment: Uh, this get's dirty soon. You could append a javascript to the iframe that removes all others stuff.

Comment: that sounds like fun... How would I get everything but that div and everything inside of it and remove that? I would haev to say something like get everything on the page and remove everything except if it is also in that div...

Comment: what about a `jQuery("*:not(#login)").remove()` ? Didn't test it :)

Comment: Like it, i wonder what would happen to the stuff inside fo the login div. i'll try it out

Comment: I tried: $('#testloadlogin iframe body:not(#loginInnerBox)').remove(); and it didn't do anything. I left out "body" and it just removed the iframe altogether. I tried: $('#iframe *:not(#loginInnerBox)').remove(); and it didn't do anything and $('#*:not(#loginInnerBox)').remove(); removed absolutely everything on the page. I think I'll start a new topic with this questions specifically.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086876/show-only-one-div-within-an-iframe-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you let a server-side program check whether the user is logged in and if not, do a HTTP redirect?

Comment: no. because the user is allowed to see some content if they are not logged in. However i just want to try to get them to login. In the end after I get this working, I would make it a Jquery dialog so they can just click the X if they don't wanna login.