# show only one div within an iframe (javascript, JQuery...)

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, html

First just let me say I'm open to ideas on a different approach altogether.

I have and iframe as such:

```
<div id="testloadlogin">
      <iframe src="../security/login.aspx" width="400" height="500"
             scrolling="auto" frameborder="1">
      [Your user agent does not support frames or is currently configured
      not to display frames. However, you may visit
      <a href="../security/login.aspx">the related document.</a>]
      </iframe>
</div>
```

The page being loaded with the iframe has a div called loginInnerBox. I only want to display the loginInnerBox and everything inside of it.

Any ideas on how to do this? I was thinking of using Jquery or javascript of some kind to remove everything else on the page loaded by the iframe, not sure how to access that though...

Just to be clear I want everything on my page outside of the iframe to remain intact. I want the equivalent of saying $.('testloadlogin').load('../security/login.aspx' #loginInnerBox) which would just get loginInnerBox's html and place it in the testloadlogin div. However I need the back-end processing from the other page which is supported by iframe, but not by the Jquery load.

The markup of the page loaded by the iframe is

```
<body>
    <div>
    </div>.......
    <div class="AspNet-Login" id="ctl00_CLPMainContent_Login1">
        <div id="loginInnerBox">
            <div id="loginCreds">
                <table>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>....
</body>
```

Do you need more information than that?

I tried this, it had no effect:

```
<div class="ui-corner-all" id="RefRes">
        <div id="testloadlogin">
        <iframe onload="javascript:loadlogin()" id="loginiframe" src="../security/login.aspx"
             scrolling="auto" frameborder="1">
      [Your user agent does not support frames or is currently configured
      not to display frames. However, you may visit
      <a href="../security/login.aspx">the related document.</a>]
      </iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadlogin() {
            $('<body>*', this.contentWindow.document).not('#ctl00_CLPMainContent_Login1').hide();
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean by "only display the box"? What do you want to happen with the other content? What about content outside the iframe?

Comment: Sorry. The rest of the content INSIDE the iframe I want to disappear. The content OUTSIDE the iframe I want to remain intact.

Comment: It will depend on the markup of the page loaded inside the iframe, how to do it, so please show the markup.

Comment: posted a general layout, i can post the while page if you would like...

Answer (score 5):

With jQuery, you can load not just the contents of a URL, but a specific CSS selector from within that URL. This would be a much cleaner approach. It's like this.

```
$("#area").load("something.html #content");
```

Via [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/ajax-load-container-contents/)

Answer (score 3):

```
$("iframe").contents().find("*:not(#loginInnerBox)").remove();
```

Be aware this would only work on iframes loaded from the same domain ([same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy))

**EDIT**: Probably this removes children of `loginInnerBox` as well. In that case you could try to clone it before:

```
var iframe   = $("iframe").contents(),
    loginBox = iframe.find("#loginInnerBox").clone();

iframe.find("*").remove();
iframe.append(loginBox);
```

Something like that..

Comment: hopefully they will be from the same domain. They are right now, just hope they don't change the domains of the site around. I'm testing now.

Comment: it didn't do anything. just shows the whole page in the iframe as before.

Comment: Hmm.. Try whether you can remove anything from the iframe contents. If `remove` won't work on iframes you might switch to `$(el).hide()`?

Comment: I tried: $('#loginInnerBox').remove(); and it did NOT remove the loginInnerBox which is within the iframe. $('#loginInnerBox').hide(); has the same effect of still showing the login box.

Comment: Accesing elements in the iframe without `$("iframe").contents()` won't work. Try to give your iframe an id and access it via `$("#iframe_id").contents()`.

Comment: neither $('#loginiframe').contents().hide(); nor $('#loginiframe').contents().remove(); does anything at all

Comment: Should be important to say that the load-event of the iframe has to fire, before accessing the content.

Answer (score -1):

Add this to the `<iframe>`-elememt:

```
onload="$('body>*',this.contentWindow.document).not('#ctl00_CLPMainContent_Login1').hide();"
```

it will hide every child of the body except #ctl00_CLPMainContent_Login1

If #ctl00_CLPMainContent_Login1 contains more than the loginbox, you have to use the suggestion using clone() posted by pex.

Comment: so if there re divs inside the loginbox ii'll have to use clone? will the same serer side code be executed when I click a button in the iframe when using clone as when not using clone?

Comment: javascript does'nt care about serverside code, and in the other way the server wo'nt care about javascript.