# Help with Google Map

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-maps

I'm attempting to help somebody out with their website, and I've just about gone crazy exhausting everything I know how to do and am now hoping a fresh pair of eyes can help.

Short and sweet:

I need to load the "map area" from this webpage:
 
http://eaglecrestredmondoregon.idxco.com/idx/10243/mapSearch.php

onto this webpage:
http://eaglecrestredmondoregon.com/

I've made some progress, but the map isn't working. I need this specific map because it updates from IDXCO.com with all the specific listings, etc.

I tried duplicating the elements from the working page into the Wordpress theme but I'm missing something... can anyone help? Or maybe suggest an alternate solution?

Thanks!

Comment: -1 for poor title and lack of information. "the map isnt working" is not enough information.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on this subject, but try looking at the examples here:

[show only one div within an iframe (javascript, JQuery...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086876/show-only-one-div-within-an-iframe-javascript-jquery)